# ReactJS arm64 docker image not working on AWS Gravitas t4g instance

Tags: node.js, reactjs, linux, amazon-web-services, docker

What I am trying to do

1. Package ReactJS app in Docker Container from Windows 11
2. Tag Image and Push to AWS ECR
3. Use same image on AWS EC2 to Run

***Building on Windows 11 with WSL 2***

```bash
docker buildx ls                                                                       ✔ ▓▒░
NAME/NODE     DRIVER/ENDPOINT STATUS                 PLATFORMS
desktop-linux                 protocol not available
default *     docker
  default     default         running                linux/amd64, linux/arm64, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/386, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6
```

**Dockerfile**

```yaml
    # FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM node:18-alpine
    FROM node:18-alpine
    
    WORKDIR .
    
    COPY package.json ./
    COPY package-lock.json ./
    RUN npm install --silent
    # RUN npm install react-scripts -g --silent
    
    # Slows down the build process copies all
    COPY .. ./
    
    # Copy only build folder which is only required in case of reactJS
    #COPY build build
    
    RUN npm run build --omit=dev
    
    # Install `serve` to run the application.
    RUN npm install --location=global serve
    
    # start app in development mode
    CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

*Docker Build CMD*

```bash
docker buildx build . --tag frontend --platform linux/arm64
```

*Docker Build output*

```bash
[+] Building 141.0s (13/13) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.2s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 705B                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.1s
 => => transferring context: 35B                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18-alpine                                                                                                                                                                                    2.5s
 => [auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.1s
 => => transferring context: 56.36kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => [1/8] FROM docker.io/library/node:18-alpine@sha256:57b98f182ea7253f213f742f1f7bac3f881adc5e40d72f5eafbf2e70bf6f6647                                                                                                                              0.0s 
 => CACHED [2/8] COPY package.json ./                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [3/8] COPY package-lock.json ./                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s 
 => CACHED [4/8] RUN npm install --silent                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s 
 => [5/8] COPY .. ./                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 1.6s
 => [6/8] RUN npm run build --omit=dev                                                                                                                                                                                                             129.5s
 => [7/8] RUN npm install --location=global serve                                                                                                                                                                                                    5.1s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                                               1.8s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                                              1.7s 
 => => writing image sha256:fadcf609c8a50f455383e2a3ee4080c91d976f5b1c7dadec6df3faa0c9bb0e15                                                                                                                                                         0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/frontend
```

*Docker Inspect Output*

```bash
docker image inspect frontend --format '{{.Os}}/{{.Architecture}}'
linux/arm64
```

As per logs, I have built a docker image that will support the `ARM64` architecture.

As I pushed this image to AWS ECR.

I am Using AWS EC2 t4x2large system which is based on  `Arm-based AWS Graviton2 processors`

```
uname -m
aarch64
```

### Problem

Docker Running on AWS Server creating the problem.

```bash
docker run -it -p 8016:3000 ****amazonaws.com/frontend:latest
exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error
```

Inspecting the image also shows that it is the same Architecture

```bash
docker image inspect ****amazonaws.com/frontend:latest --format '{{.Os}}/{{.Architecture}}'
linux/arm64
```

But when I am building the same image from the same dockerfile on AWS it is working as expected and the output to that is

```bash
docker image inspect frontend:latest --format '{{.Os}}/{{.Architecture}}'
linux/arm64
```

This problem I am facing only in ReactJS build ...

---

***I used python image to build the arm64 image to run on AWS and it is working fine build was done from windows 11 itself.***

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: An `exec format error` most likely means you're trying to execute code that is not compatible with Graviton2.   With the problem container, have you tried entering it interactively and inspecting the format of the binaries with `readelf -h`?

Comment: I'm facing the same kind of issue. "standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error" How did you fix this or is it fixed ?